# Headless Selenium on Amazon Linux ami

Tags: selenium, amazon-web-services, headless-browser

I'm trying to run Selenium Headless on an Amazon Linux ami.  I've found a script to test it locally:

```rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'headless'

@headless = Headless.new
@headless.start
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

@driver.get 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com'
@driver.title.should == 'The Internet'
@driver.save_screenshot 'example1.png'

@driver.quit
@headless.destroy
```

I've installed `firefox 33` to match `selenium web-driver 2.44`.  When I run `ruby example1.rb` I get an error:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:79:in `connect_until_stable': unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:37:in `block in launch'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:20:in `locked'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:32:in `launch'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `new'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from example1.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

My impression is the headless gem is supposed to handle starting up the service and destroying it on the `.start` and `.destroy` call.  Anyone have suggestions for making this work?

Comment: Do you have `xvfb` installed on the server? It's required for Headless to work.

Comment: I do have it installed `yum install Xvfb`.

Comment: Killed the box, started over with an Ubuntu version.  Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got this worked out, but if anyone else finds this post, I wanted to add that Chrome now supports running in a headless mode so you can skip xvfb.
This link provides a good outline, but you will want to use the latest version of chromedriver: https://gist.github.com/maciekkolodziej/b383c0b956b4f89c6f19a358a468237b
This is also helpful if you are on a Fedora instance rather than Umbuntu: http://w3h4ppyf3w.tumblr.com/post/114033055263/using-yum-to-install-google-chrome-on-aws-linux